# Upgrading to Python 3.4 from 3.2

Tags: 12.04, python3

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and Python 3.2 installed. When I use `sudo apt-get install python3`, it says that my python is 'already the newest version'. However, 3.4 is the latest.

How would I upgrade my current Python to 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ships with python3 3.2.3. If you need Python 3, then I suggest to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which includes python3 3.4.1.

If you cannot do that, consider something like [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html).

Comment: Surely there has to be a way of installing 3.4 without reinstalling the OS!

Comment: @BetaDecay Upgrade, not reinstall. Python 3 is a core component that is used by various parts of Ubuntu. Upgrading it system-wide may introduce breakage. The safest way is then to upgrade your current LTS to the next LTS version which is tested quite well. If you really want to keep your current version, have a look at virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

You can build from source. Download the tarball from the [Python-site](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-341/).

```
$tar xvf Python-4.3.1.tgz
$cd Python-4.3.1
$less README
```

And follow the instructions. You will then have two different installations of python so by just entering `$python -v` you will invoke the old python version. This could be fixed by linking the new to your `/etc/bin/python` or whatever it links to. First you need to remove the old link and create a new.

```
$rm /etc/bin/openssl
$ln -s [PATH TO NEW PYTHON] /etc/bin/openssl
```

Now the new Python should be invoked, check with:

```
$python -v
```